# Cell reference dynamically

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to change the offset reference based on drop down list. How could I do it? I used offset reference manually. Hope my question is clear.Thanking you in advance.
[image: Reference Image]

Comment: Use name manager instead.

Comment: @Harun24hr We have more than 20 names .I will try it, thanks

Comment: The two sheets shown are in different workbooks?  I was going to suggest `INDIRECT` and using tables but pretty sure `INDIRECT` won't work on a closed workbook.

Comment: With everything in the same file and your data in tables named _Collected_, _Received_, _Sales_ the formula `=INDIRECT(A3 & "[#All]")` would work.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook Yes both are in different sheets. Thank you.:-)

Comment: Different sheets or different files?

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook Book3 having data &  from Book3 I need to get the data to Book2 using the formula as mentioned in the image. Book2, Book3 are different files.